# Deploying with capistrano fails to update js and css files. How to clear cached files?

Tags: javascript, caching, deployment, capistrano, updates

I'm using capistrano to deploy from localhost to the remote server.
Everytging works fine except one thing: js and css files do not update. Not even one. Not even application.js or application.css is updated on the server.

What should I do to make capistrano update js and css files? I think they are cached so I only need to clear this cache files. How do I do that? I think this is a common question but I could not find any information about.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your Capfile and deploy.rb?

Comment: Yes, sure. But I think there is some common rule to use in that case, in example `set :clear_cache, :true`. If there is, please tell me about it. If there is no, I can post my deploy files.

Comment: In a vanilla Capistrano deploy, assets are kept in public and served by the web server (eg. Nginx), not Rails. There is no caching of assets per se.

Comment: Thank you, cmaitchison. I found out that somehow my js and css files are updated but there is another problem (js is not working, except if it is run through the browser console). I think I will fix it on my own.